# the .map() method is not mapping all the values of the dictionary in a dataframe column. Is there a way around this?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have prepared a dictionary with keys as 1 to 10, each corresponding to a color. I want to map this dictionary to the corresponding values in a column of a data-frame.

The dictionary looks like this:

```
color_dict = {'1':'white' ,'2':'black' ,'3':'brown' ,'4':'red' ,'5':'orange' ,'6':'yellow' ,'7':'green' ,'8':'blue' ,'9':'purple' ,'10':'grey'}
```

The column i am trying to map this dictionary to looks like this:

```
col_happy.head()
```

[original column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWLEu.png)
The values correspond to a color as labelled in the color_dict dictionary.

After applying the `.map()` of pandas, i got the output like this:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVxKR.png)
Somehow, map function is not mapping all the values into the column. How to solve this?

Comment: Does your column contain strings or numbers? Ie. is it `6` or `'6'`? Because you used strings as keys in your dict, but I think you used a mix of strings and numbers in your dataframe.

Comment: the data type is object. How to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(color_dict.items())
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
0       1
0   1   white
1   2   black
2   3   brown
3   4     red
4   5  orange
5   6  yellow
6   7   green
7   8    blue
8   9  purple
9  10    grey
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not sure if the values are `str` or `int` so u can modify the dictionary to have both -

```
color_dict = {'1':'white',  1:'white',
              '2':'black',  2:'black',
              '3':'brown',  3:'brown',
              '4':'red',    4:'red',
              '5':'orange', 5:'orange',
              '6':'yellow', 6:'yellow',
              '7':'green',  7:'green',
              '8':'blue',   8:'blue',
              '9':'purple', 9:'purple',
              '10':'grey',  10:'grey'}
```

If your dataframe is like this as shown in the image-

```
   0
0  4
1  6
2  7
3  9
4  2
```

Then do this -

```
# Again the column name can also be 0: int, '0': str
# so using iloc instead

df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0].map(color_dict)
```

Output-

```
0       red
1    yellow
2     green
3    purple
4     black
```

Comment: this didn't quite give me the result. it generated the same output as the one i shared as image earlier. I am pretty sure the values are string values...the output doesn't quite change if i use .replace() either..it just leaves the numbers as is

Comment: How about: `df.iloc[:,0] = df.iloc[:,0].map(str).map(color_dict)` ?

Comment: Try this: df.iloc[,:0].apply(int) to change whole column to int as '1' will become 1 and ' 1' will also become 1